# Python: Why is `lambda` faster than a function or multiplication?

Tags: python, function, numpy, lambda

Doing simple multiplication seem that `lambda` is faster; why?

```
import numpy as np
import time

def mult(x=None, y=None): return x*y

x = np.random.rand(10000,10000)

f = lambda z, g: z*g

start = []
end = []

for i in xrange(100):
    start.append(time.time())
    x*5
    end.append(time.time())

start = np.array(start)
end = np.array(end)

print np.sum(end-start)/len(end)

start = []
end = []

for i in xrange(100):

    start.append(time.time())
    f(x, 5)
    end.append(time.time())

start = np.array(start)
end = np.array(end)

print np.sum(end-start)/len(end)

start = []
end = []

for i in xrange(100):

    start.append(time.time())
    mult(x, 5)
    end.append(time.time())

start = np.array(start)
end = np.array(end)

print np.sum(end-start)/len(end)
```

I get:

```
0.487183141708
0.482636857033
0.483230319023
```

Comment: You should use `timeit` to benchmark your code: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: you should use https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html to measure the performance and then paste the difference.

Comment: I get `x * 5` *454 ms ± 4.86 ms per loop*, `f(x, 5)` *472 ms ± 17.3 ms per loop* and `mult(f, 5)` *458 ms ± 5 ms per loop*...

Comment: Those differences are statistically insignificant

Comment: So one single run, on one particular machine, in one particular order, gives a time for `lambda` that's marginally smaller than the two other times. That doesn't constitute good evidence that `lambda` is faster. I'd suggest running several times, and also varying the order in which the three timings are performed within the script. You can then do a statistical test to discover whether any difference you see is significant. If `lambda` is _consistently_ faster across hundreds of runs, regardless of the ordering, then there may be something worth investigating.

Comment: The `lambda` just adds in a layer of function calling.  It doesn't change the calculation.  For small arrays that added layer should be noticeable in the times.  For large ones it disappears in the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`timeit`](https://kite.com/python/docs/timeit) module:

```
import numpy as np

def mult(x=None, y=None):
    return x*y
x = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
f = lambda z, g: z*g


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    setup_str = "from __main__ import x, f, mult"
    print(timeit.timeit('x*5', number=100, setup=setup_str))
    print(timeit.timeit('f(x, 5)', number=100, setup=setup_str))
    print(timeit.timeit('mult(x, 5)', number=100, setup=setup_str))
```

Output

> 0.3345440280099865
>
> 0.42724098000326194
>
> 0.3455269880068954

Comment: Seems like lambda is slowest.